# Method classpath() can not be found

Tags: android

I have the following error :

org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Here's my build.gradle (App)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

     dependencies {
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
         classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
     }

     android {
         compileSdkVersion 30
         buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

         defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.xxx"
             minSdkVersion 14
             targetSdkVersion 26
             versionCode 1
             versionName "0.01"
       }
         buildTypes {
             release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
       }
     }
```

And the build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options   common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
       classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
      }
    }
  }
```

what did I do wrong ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Onik: This is the app module's `build.gradle` -- notice the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` at the top.

Comment: The two `classpath` lines belong in the `dependencies` closure in the top-level `build.gradle` file -- the one in your project root directory. It should already have the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'` line, but you could add the `classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'` line there.

Comment: I added in the build.gradle of the project root directory (see above) and still not works

Comment: You also need to remove it from the module's `build.gradle`.

Comment: If I delete, I obtain the new error Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found